# What odd maneuver is this for a cruising airplane?

Tags: air-traffic-control, airliner

Several years ago, I saw a set 4-5 of con-trails converging at nearly the same time and height. They were each executing large turns (90 to 300 degrees) over the same space, starting from various directions, and leaving from various. This took over/near Kansas City Int'l (MCI).

Sadly, I failed to take a pic.

Recently, I got another pic! Same location, apparent altitude, same high-degree turn, but only one con-trail.

What would cause a plane (or 4 planes!) to make such large turns? Surely diverting to a new airport would only cause a minor deviation from cruising alt.

Both times I was 17.5 mi south of MCI.  I think I've probability mis-characterised their altitude.

[image: con-trail]

Comment: Once in a while I also see something very very similar to that over my head and they are from jet fighters... training or just having fun :)

Comment: Can you give us an idea of where this is? There may an area they are not allowed to overfly, and they have to make this little "detour". Or it may be the junction between two airways which avoid that area. For instance North of Las Vegas there's a large area with no airways, so the airways on the sides have pretty large angles between them.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you wrote this was near MCI. Can you let us know the direction you were facing when you took the picture, and possibly where relative to MCI you were? Also, did you check on flightradar24 or flightaware for any flights around that date/time?

Comment: Both times I saw this, I was 17.5 mi due S of MCI.  I.e., facing north.  I'm probably wrong about them being at cruising alt.

Comment: Is the question about the single "bright" trail that turns, or the multiple wispy faint trails that diverge progressively from the line that looks like the edge of a thin high cirrus cloud? The latter are more interesting to me! The shape looks like a military "overhead break" where a formation splits to land, but that's not normally done at high altitude.

Comment: If you look at the airways in the area on skyvector.com you'll see it could be an aircraft coming from J80 or J26 going to J41 for instance. Depending on where they are coming from/going to it's probably not an ideal routing, but there could be some issue on the more direct routing that would have sent them this way. Next time you see this, look up flightradar24 (you can install the app on your phone) to see what flight it is, it could help explain exactly why they are doing this. Note that it is quite possible it happens very often but you only notice it when they leave contrails.

Comment: The question is about the single, bright con-trail.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They were probably "stacked up" in a *holding pattern* while waiting for permission to land at a busy airport. This is a common occurrence and the flying maps that pilots use will have a "racetrack" marked up near the destination airport. If things are too busy on the ground to manage incoming traffic, the air traffic controller will instruct the pilot of an arriving plane to divert and "hold as published", which means proceed to the racetrack and go round in circles until you get the all-clear instruction.

Each plane in the holding pattern is assigned their own altitude to circle in, and the ATC will pluck the bottom-most plane out of the stack and clear them to land. Then all the other planes that are stacked up are reassigned the next-lower altitude to hold on and the whole stack "drops" down one level.

This puts the plane that has been holding the longest at the bottom of the stack, and the newest plane to arrive is inserted into the topmost level in the stack.

ADDED IN EDIT:
As pointed out by others here, course changes like the one pictured are often performed by military aircraft, performing maneuvers on training flights. You can pick these out from the ground by noting that such flights do not generally follow the airway patterns for your area. For example, in western Oregon between Eugene and Portland, all the commercial flights high enough to pull contrails follow north-south lines. A jet at cruise that flies overhead here on an *east-west* track is therefore not a commercial flight because there are no commercial destinations along that line.

BTW once on a flight between Portland and the SFO bay area, our pilot announced that ATC wanted us to arrive 5 minutes or so later than scheduled and in response the pilot made a slow right circle, at cruise. This was approximately over the Oregon-California border. I do not know how often passenger jets get instructed to "hold at cruise" like this.

Comment: I've heard of racetracks, but I've never heard of them being *at cruising altitude* before.  Can that be right?  Do planes really circle up to 200 miles from the airport?

Comment: yikes.  If the 5000' plane doesn't get word to descend to 4000', then the 6000' plane will smack into it when it descends to 5000'.  You'd need a positive means to ensure the 5000' guy got the order.  Obviously you can do that once or twice safely enough... the problem is, you have to get it right every single time.

Comment: @Harper, This is routinely done every day. In an ATC's training, they are required to drop a stack of five planes or more sequentially, *by memory*, in case their radar displays fail and they have to manage the racetrack by hand.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica You can be sure that it's a solved problem. Basically any flaw in the system, that you can think of, if you aren't heavily involved in the matter, has been dealt with decades ago.

Comment: This answer is accurate in describing holding, but I’m not convinced it’s applicable to the photo.  All I see is a course change.

Comment: @MichaelHall I'm not convinced either, although I suppose it could be a direct entry to a holding pattern, assuming the aircraft is flying away from the camera and then turning clockwise.

Comment: @Michael - Planes can't circle 200 miles "straight up" - that would be into orbit!  Cruising altitude is ~32k feet, only 6 miles, but the stack starts far below that.  From a quick back-of-the-envelope calculation, it appears that a leg of the track is ~4 (nautical) miles, so they're not going 200 miles from the airport horizontally either...

Comment: I can’t imagine a stack ever forming at MCI. It’s just not that busy.

Comment: I question the idea of planes stacked in a holding pattern *up at the contrail level*, regardless of specific location.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse -- That was the point of Michael's comment too-- regardless of the validity of the specific "200 mile" figure, if you are holding *that high* (high enough to leave a contrail), you still have a *long* linear descent leg ahead of you -- unless you are following a *really* inefficient flight path. (No one was suggesting that planes were circling at an *altitude* of 200 miles, or that the *actual holding pattern* included a 200-mile leg!) –

Answer (score 6):

In my experience as an observer, aircraft performing *large turns* (greater than say a simple 45-degree "bend" in the flight path) up at the contrail level have a greater-than-average chance of being military rather than commercial aircraft.  Always a good reason to break out the binoculars and see what aircraft is leaving the trail.

From your description, it's difficult to tell whether any of the aircraft were *actually flying together in close proximity*, or not.  If so, aerial refueling comes to mind as a possible explanation.  But one can imagine many other scenarios, including various training exercises, where one or more military aircraft would follow a flight path that was configured to prioritize objectives *other* than simply transiting from point A to point B as efficiently as possible.

Comment: The usual objection about not invalidating existing answers notwithstanding, perhaps the question could be modified to address the last paragraph of this answer --

Comment: Both times I was 17.5 mi south of MCI.  I think I've probability mis-characterised their altitude.  No known military activity that I know of there.

Comment: A tanker on an aerial refueling mission seems like the most probable explanation... especially for the not-photographed case of several contrails doing similar things... one or two tankers & multiple receivers, all following similar tracks.

Comment: Edited question to remove mention of plan(es) being at cruising altitude. I do not the altitude.

Comment: @user1745937 -- to me the edit doesn't really change anything, and wouldn't have affected my answer, the point is that they were high enough to make contrails, which is pretty much only going to happen up at the levels that a jet would consider using for long-range cruising flight, or at least somewhere kind of close to that.   (Google "at what altitude do contrails form").  And to the best of my knowledge, the "holds" mentioned in other answers are not *routinely* executed that high, though one answer does detail one specific exception, a single circle performed to delay the arrival.

Comment: @nielsnielson -- PS one reason that we know that it's rare for traffic to be *holding* up at the contrail levels, is that if this were common, the *chem-trail conspiracy buffs* (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemtrail_conspiracy_theory ) would be constantly talking about aircraft spraying chemtrails while flying in ovals.  But they don't.  Instead, they talk about spraying while "flying in a grid pattern"--

Comment: -- which is actually exactly the *expected* pattern resulting when the whole airmass is advecting (moving) diagonally, in relation to a couple of well-used linear airliner "tracks" that happen to intersect at a near 90-degree angle.